# Trying to return IEnumerable of two joined tables from LINQ query

Tags: asp.net, linq, api

This is starting to do my head in....

I have two tables in my database:

### Tickets

```
public string id { get; set; }
public int assigned_to { get; set; }
...
public virtual Users Users { get; set; }
```

### Users

```
public int id { get; set; }
public string email { get; set; }
...
public virtual Tickets Tickets { get; set; }
```

I am trying to join these tables together to return an `IEnumerable<>` of the tickets table where each ticket has a corresponding user.  The two tables are joined by Tickets.assigned_to = Users.id

So far I have tried both:

```
var query = from t in _context.Tickets
            join u in _context.Users on t.assigned_to equals u.id
            select (new {t, u});

return query.ToList();
```

And

```
IEnumerable<Tickets> query = from t in _context.Tickets
                             join u in _context.Users on t.assigned_to equals u.id
                             select (new {t, u});

return query.ToList();
```

But both give me the error:
`Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<<anonymous type: DataWire.Models.Tickets t, DataWire.Models.Users u>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<DataWire.Models.Tickets>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`

Note: This is for a ASP.NET Web API where I am trying to return a list of Tickets from my Repository.

Answer (score 1):

Don't return a new {t, u} as this is an anonymous type containing both Tickets and User - not an IEnumerable of just Tickets. You want:

```
IEnumerable<Tickets> query = from t in _context.Tickets
                         join u in _context.Users on t.assigned_to equals u.id
                         select (t);

return query.ToList();
```

Comment: Far out, I can't believe I've been banging my head against the wall and it was that simple...  that has worked, however, it seems to be returning `"Users":null` for every ticket, and I know that every ticket has an `assigned_to` value.

Comment: As a virtual member it's lazy loading so the Users property won't be populated until you reference it in your code or explicitly Include() Users.

Comment: Sorry strickt01, could you please elaborate on that a bit more.  How do I explicitly include() Users?  I did try using the `.Include()` but I couldn't get the join to work correctly.

Comment: Bracket out your entire `from` query and then add `.Include(t => t.Users)`

Comment: Yes, that is what I tried.  `return _context.Tickets.Include(t => t.Users).ToList();` gives me the following error: `Error 1: 'no such column: u.Ticketsid'`.  I gather it's because I don't have corresponding fields in both tables?

Comment: Sorry, I now understand what you meant in your last comment.  I have tried that but still get the error: `Error 1: 'no such column: u0.Ticketsid`

Comment: There may be a number of issues at play. For starters, I presume that there is a one-to-many relationship between Users and Tickets. Thus Users should have an `ICollection<Tickets>` rather than just a single `Tickets` reference. Without seeing you entire entity class structure it is difficult to tell. Also you will need to set the relationship up in your context: `modelBuilder.Entity<Users>().HasMany(e => e.Tickets).WithRequired(e => e.Users).HasForeignKey(e => e.assigned_to)` (or similar...)

Comment: It seems I have gone around in a full circle.  I cannot use your code snippet as (for some unknown reason) I cannot use the command DbModelBuilder within my code.  Adding references creates a multitude of errors and breaks everything else.  I really don't know where to go from here.

Comment: We seem to have strayed from the original question somewhat. If, as it seems, my answer was correct, can you mark it as such and we can look at EF class issues via a chat?

Comment: I am happy to mark this as accepted as I can see 'logically' that your answer should work.  However, due to the various EF errors I'm receiving, I am unable to test properly and give an accurate answer.  Happy to chat further to resolve this.

Comment: Sure. I'm pretty busy today but the first port of call would be to work out what version of EF you are using and whether it is code first/database first/code first with database etc....

Comment: I finally have my code working, but I cannot use the `.WithRequired` command as suggested in your code snippet as it is not recognized in EF7, only `WithOne`.

Comment: I can't help with EF7 I'm afraid. We started using it and were advised by Microsoft to continue with EF6 until EF7 was working!

Comment: can I contact you personally with help trying to get EF6 working?  I want to mark your answer, but I need to simulate it working.